# Adding pretty query parameters

Tags: url-rewriting, urls

A custom post type named shooting has a field (with ACF) with plenty of images. Those are listed on the `single.php` of the CPT and one of those images is displayed in full-ish size. I currently have URLs like `shooting/foo-bar/?image=1` where 1 is the index (not ID) of the image that should be displayed large.

Is there a way to get prettier URLs like `shooting/foo-bar/1` with WordPress? Or would I have to write a custom rewrite-rule for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a custom rewrite rule for that:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

I think you might have a hard time though, with it being within an area of the site (single post type) already using a custom rewrite rule!

Comment: why do you think I'd have a hard time? Are there pitfalls I should watch out for?

Comment: Just from experience using the rewrite api. I'm sure it'd be possible. Make sure to refresh your permalinks after setting a new rewrite rule. You can do this by visiting the Settings > Permalinks page. no need to save anything, just visiting that page refreshes all the rewrite rules. There's a also a PHP snippet to do the same.